# Menu item only show in overflow bar not in main bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The action item only show in overflow bar instead of main action bar in android  and as I read the head first android 2nd edition it says that this is a bug in v7 appcompact library.  So how can I fix it.should I reinstall my android studio or update it?

Comment: provide code or screenshot

Comment: Are you using the attribute `android:showAsAction="always"`?

Comment: yes I have tried that but same issue

Comment: yes i have tried that but not working

Comment: I think there is not any solution for this problem.